# What is this site? Is it plagiarizing us?

Tags: support

When answering a question recently, I did a google search for a certain phrase that appeared in that post. One of the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdTRD.png) was to [this](https://atepifefez.com/?_=%2F%23EP3q9%2BD%2FMkxAqO%2FU2%2F15Ma%2FscgGMYxknqs8iRNqmwtMX5A%3D%3D) site, called *atepifefez.com*.

It's literally the Hinduism.SE site, hosted by a third-party. I encourage you to poke around: all the links work, it's clickable, and it's basically a duplicate site. I don't know what SE's policy is about licensing and content, but it seems to me that it's plagiarism. (It loads pretty slowly, though)

Does anyone else know what it is? Is it supposed to be there, is it okay, or is it violating some sort of rule? Am I making a big deal out of nothing?

Comment: Have updated the answer, you may want to take appropriate action.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - will do do when I get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update: Just found [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423587), quoting:**

> This looks like a website is proxying ours; it's also naturally a copyright and trademark violation.
>
> In cases like this, where a website is copying (or proxying) the entirety of what Stack Overflow looks like, the correct path is to report it through the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/206319) form. We will then loop-in our legal team so that they can take appropriate measures.

---

It seems the site is loading HSE site within other domain i.e. atepifefez.com.

### Now what we can do?

###### Short answer is: *We really can't do anything.*

I'll just quote from [the meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/206319) which have addressed this concern already:

> ### What actions can I take myself?
>
> There are some actions you can take yourself:
>
> - If you see a blog post or other page which copied a post from you or someone else and it's just a one-off deal, you should feel free to contact the author as a concerned member of the community. There is nothing wrong with a user pointing out the rules and hopefully getting an author to fix their content as well as educating them about our attribution requirements.
> - If you've found a site proxying our content and serving malware, you can also report the site directly to Google using the [spam report tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport), in addition to contacting us as above.
> - If the website contains Google AdSense ads, you can [report their abuse of ads to Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1190500). Other advertising networks may have similar report systems.
> - **If you are the author of any content that has been scraped from our site**, you may find some of the below resources useful. We cannot give you legal advice here, though, and you will need to investigate any recourse you can take on your own.
>
> - Creative Commons, [*What happens if I offer my material under a Creative Commons license and someone misuses them?*](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-happens-if-i-offer-my-material-under-a-creative-commons-license-and-someone-misuses-them) and [case law](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Case_Law).
> - Free Software Foundation, [*The Principles of Community-Oriented GPL Enforcement*](https://fsf.org/licensing/enforcement-principles) and [*GPL violations*](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-violation.html).
> - Wikipedia community in various languages, [standard enforcement letter and DMCA complaint](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4994074).